# Swift - Array with specific class type

Tags: arrays, swift

How can i create array which will hold objects belonging a specific class.

```
class BaseObject {}

class Derived1: BaseObject {}
class Derived2: BaseObject {}
class Derived2: BaseObject {}
```

I need to create array in which will hold only Object derived from `BaseObject`

Something like - `var array : [BaseObject.Type] = []`

Is there a way to specify this ?

Also, I should be able to use it something like this

```
if let derived1 = object as? [Derived1] {

}
else if let derived2 = object as? [Derived2] {

}
```

Comment: `var array = [BaseObject]()`

Comment: I want to restrict array to use a specific class object. If i create an array with base class. Then i can add any derived class, i rather want to restrict it to use only 1 derived type based on instance created.

Comment: If you *want to restrict it to use only 1 derived type*  – which contradicts the information in the question – use `var array = [Derived1]()`

Comment: So basically you need to have an array that is declared as a heterogenous array, but behaves like an homogenous one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can obviously define your array as an array of `BaseObject`:

```
var objects: [BaseObject] = []  // or `var objects = [BaseObject]()`
```

But it's going to let you create a heterogenous collection (of either `BaseObject` or `Derived1` or `Derived2` or of any other subclass). That's a core OO design concept (the [Liskov substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle)) that any subclass of `BaseObject` should (and will) be permitted.

If all you want is to say that you can only have an array of one of the subtypes, you can obviously just define your array as such, e.g.:

```
var objects: [Derived1] = []
```

That will obviously allow only `Derived1` objects (and any subclasses of `Derived1`.

---

90% of the time, the above is sufficient. But in some cases, you might needs some collection with methods that require some inherited base behavior, but for which you don't want to allow heterogenous collections. In this case, I might consider a more protocol-oriented pattern:

1. Bottom line, should we be subclassing, or should we be using a protocol-oriented approach? I.e. is `BaseObject` actually something you'll instantiate for its own purposes, or is it there merely to define some common behavior of the subclasses. If the latter, a protocol might be a better pattern, e.g.:

   ```
   protocol Fooable {
       func foo()
   }

   // if you want, provide some default implementation for `foo` in an
   // protocol extension

   extension Fooable {
       func foo() {
           // does something unique to objects that conform to this protocol
       }
   }

   struct Object1: Fooable {}
   struct Object2: Fooable {}
   struct Object3: Fooable {}
   ```

   This yields the sort of behavior that you may have been using in your more OO approach, but using protocols. Specifically, you write one `foo` method that all of the types that conform to this protocol, e.g., `Object1`, `Object2`, etc., can use without having to implement `foo` themselves (unless, of course, you want to because they need special behavior for some reason).
2. Because this eliminates the subclassing, this then opens the door for the use of generics and protocols that dictate some generalized behavior while dictating the homogenous nature of the members. For example:

   ```
   struct FooCollection<T: Fooable> {
       private var array = [T]()

       mutating func append(_ object: T) {
           array.append(object)
       }

       // and let's assume you need some method for your collection that
       // performs some `Fooable` task for each instance

       func fooAll() {
           array.forEach { $0.foo() }
       }
   }
   ```

   This is a generic which is a homogenous collection of objects that conform to your protocol. For example, when you go to use it, you'd declare a particular type of `Fooable` type to use:

   ```
   var foo = FooCollection<Object1>()

   foo.append(Object1())  // permitted
   foo.append(Object2())  // not permitted

   foo.fooAll()
   ```

Now, I only went down this road because in comments elsewhere, you were inquiring about generics. I'd personally only go down this road if the (a) collection really needed to be homogenous; and (b) the collection also wanted to implement some shared logic common to the protocol. Otherwise, I'd probably just stick with a simple `[Derived1]` (or `[Object1]`). The above can be powerful when needed, but is overkill for simpler situations.

For more discussion about protocol oriented programming, the homogenous vs heterogenous behavior, traditional stumbling blocks when you're coming from a traditional OO mindset, I'd refer you to the WWDC 2015 video, [Protocol-Oriented Programming in Swift](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015/408/), or it's [2016 companion video](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/419/) that builds upon the 2015 video.

Finally, if you have any additional questions, I'd suggest you edit your question providing details on a practical problem that you're trying to solve with this pattern. Discussions in the abstract are often not fruitful. But if you tell us what the actual problem you're trying to solve with the pattern in your question, it will be a far more constructive conversation.

Comment: This is what i was looking for. Thanks @Rob